# What were the questions to Rowling's seven FAQ answers?

Tags: harry-potter, jk-rowling

A few days ago, Rowling had updated her twitter bio with<sup>1</sup>:

> FAQ answers: 1) Because the Basilisk didn't kill him 2) Next year, I hope 3) Yes 4) Wait and see 5) No, he isn't 6) No, he really isn't 7) Yes, I'm sure.

As I understand it, Rowling only directly confirmed what the last three were referring to, but can any of the others be determined?

### What are the seven questions to Rowling's twitter bio FAQ?

---

<sup>1. This was taken down shortly afterwards as it had somehow caused people to sent attack Rowling based off of a false assumption they had made.</sup>

Comment: What did people think the questions were that caused them to react negatively?

Comment: Were 5), 6), and 7): Is Harry a Horcrux?

Comment: 1) is probably “Why was the piece of Voldemort’s soul in Harry not destroyed?”

Comment: 2) seems like it should be “When is the second *Fantastic Beasts* film coming out?”

Comment: 3) and 4) might be “Will there be any more Harry Potter works?” and “When?”

Comment: "No, the last three ‘answers’ in my bio refer to the person who has dominated my notifications for the past 5 days." -JKR That person BTW is UK Labour leader Jeremy Corbyn. As for the rest... Speculate away, but unless she answers it herself, no certain answer can be had.

Comment: Since this question is not really *about* the basilisk, but merely *mentions* it, I got rid of the [tag:basilisk] tag.

Answer (score 4):

Pretty sure she hasn’t said this explicitly, so I’m going to guess! Pretty sure I have at least 4 of 7.

Some of these I’m more sure about than others.

1. **When Harry was stabbed by the Basilisk in *Chamber of Secrets*, why wasn’t the bit of Voldemort’s soul inside him destroyed?**

   This is the easiest to infer this from the answer, and [she’s said in interviews](http://www.the-leaky-cauldron.org/2007/10/20/j-k-rowling-at-carnegie-hall-reveals-dumbledore-is-gay-neville-marries-hannah-abbott-and-scores-more) that “I have been asked that a lot”.
2. (Guessing) **Something to do with *The Cursed Child*.**

   Seems like a reference to current affairs.

   Adamant speculated in the comments that it might be something to do with *Fantastic Beasts*, but the first film is coming out next November, and [the studio have announced](http://www.hypable.com/fantastic-beasts-movie-sequel-threequel-release-date/) that the sequel has a 2018 release date.
   That’s unlikely to change.

   The only other big-ticket current news item around Harry Potter is *Cursed Child* – perhaps a question of whether Warner Bros. will decide to make it into a film? (Or announce it, at least.) The rumour’s been flying around a lot lately, so possibly qualifies as an FAQ.
3. (Totally guessing) **Would you vote to remain in a second Scottish independence referendum?**

   Really, “Yes” could be the answer to anything. But what the heck.

   Background: in 2014, Scotland had [a referendum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scottish_independence_referendum,_2014) on whether to become independent from the rest of the UK, voting to stay by 55%. Rowling was a vocal proponent of the campaign to stay in the UK, and took a proportionate amount of flak for it on Twitter. As far as I know, her stance on this hasn’t changed.

   Earlier this year, the UK [voted to leave the EU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Kingdom_European_Union_membership_referendum,_2016), but Scotland was very pro-Remain. This has led to suggestions from Scottish politicians that Scotland could hold a second independence referendum. Hypothetically, they’d leave the UK, and stay in the EU as an independent country, to avoid “being dragged out of the EU against its will”.

   So maybe people are asking her whether she’d vote the same way in this hypothetical turn of events.

   Alternative guess: **Are you sure that *The Cursed Child* isn’t a sequel?** because the fact that people kept asking this was a running joke on her Twitter a few months ago.
4. (Guessing) **Something something what happens in *Fantastic Beasts*?**

   I think “wait and see” implies it’s something we already know about, but haven’t seen yet. I haven’t been following enough *Beasts* rumours to make a specific suggestion.

As for 5–7, Rowling [said in a follow-up tweet](https://twitter.com/jk_rowling/status/773214167771873281):

> No, the last three ‘answers’ in my bio refer to the person who has dominated my notifications for the past 5 days.

This is surely the politician [Jeremy Corbyn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeremy_Corbyn). For non-UK readers, Corbyn is the leader of the UK Labour Party, and his leadership of the party has been somewhat controversial. He’s towards the left of the recent Labour party, and has drawn criticism from many sides – including from Rowling herself.

Some of Corbyn’s fans have been drawing comparisons between Dumbledore and Corbyn, because they both have beards. The resemblance is striking:

[image]

Rowling has been [asking people to stop drawing the comparison](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/films/2016/08/31/jk-rowling-jeremy-corbyn-is-not-dumbledore/), and taking a fair amount of flak for it. So here are my guesses for some flippant questions:

5. **Is Jeremy Corbyn Dumbledore?**
6. **No, seriously, is Jeremy Corbyn Dumbledore?**
7. **Are you *sure* that Jeremy Corbyn isn’t Dumbledore?**

Comment: Are you ***sure*** you have the pictures labelled correctly?

Comment: No silly, he's identical to Richard Harris' Dumbledore.

Comment: I think you have accidentally switched off the labels </geeksniped>

Comment: #2 (and maybe #4 as well) are most likely related to the Corman Strike series.